# Jacoco doesn't detect interfaces

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, jacoco

I have configured Jacoco so that it generates a coverage reports when unit tests run.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unit-test-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        <destFile>${jacoco.report.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>unit-test-report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${jacoco.report.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${jacoco.report.directory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But for some reason it skips the dao package of the project, which contains the `Spring Data Jpa` repositories interfaces.

For example, the following interface:

```
import com.shaunyl.website.dao;

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Product p",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Product p")
    Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

has the following test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class ProductRepositoryTests {

    private static final int INVENTORY_SIZE = 5;

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    private Category[] categories;

    private List<Product> inventory;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        inventory = productRepository.saveAll(products(INVENTORY_SIZE));
        categories = inventory.stream().map(Product::getCategory).toArray(Category[]::new);
    }

@Test
public void shouldRetrieveOnePageOfProducts() {
    // given
    int PAGE = 0;
    int SIZE = 20;
    Pageable pageable = newUnsortedPage(PAGE, SIZE);

    // when
    Page<Product> products = productRepository.findAll(pageable);

    // then
    assertThat(products.getNumber()).isEqualTo(PAGE);
    assertThat(products.getNumberOfElements()).isEqualTo(INVENTORY_SIZE);
    assertThat(products)
            .as("categories are eagerly fetched")
            .extracting(Product::getCategory)
            .containsExactlyInAnyOrder(categories);
 }
}
```

But in the Jacoco report, the dao package is skipped.
I believe it's because the target class is instead an interface but I am not sure.

Do you know what could be the problem, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JaCoCo measures **executable Java code**. And in your interface

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Product p",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Product p")
    Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

there is no executable Java code, only declaration of method and annotation that uses constants.

This is also explained in [JaCoCo FAQ](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html):

> #### Why are abstract methods not shown in coverage reports?
>
> Abstract methods do not contain code, therefore code coverage cannot be evaluated. Indeed code coverage is recorded for subclasses implementing these methods. The same applies to non-default methods in interfaces.

Comment: But if you create a default method in your ProductRepository does Jacoco measure coverage for it? Its not working for me.

Comment: What's the best way to move forward? Set that directory to be ignored by jacoco coverage report? Live with the fact that it's showing no test coverage when there actually is test coverage?